# Contour plot, TypeError: Length of y must be number of rows in z

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I have created a function with two arguments, `func(x,y)`. I would now like to plot this as a 2D contour plot, first as `func(x,y)` vs. `x`, and then `func(x,y)` vs. `y`.

I set my numpy array for x-values as 20 values from `5e4` to `8e4`, and the y-values as 20 values from `1e10` to `1e12`. My function `func(x,y)` then takes these two arrays as arguments.

So, I set up my plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

x = np.logspace( 5e4, 8e4, num=20) 
y = np.logspace(1e10, 1e12, num=20)
z = np.asarray([ func(x, y), x ])
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

The shapes for my numpy arrays are:

```
print x.shape
print y.shape
print z.shape
```

which outputs

```
(20,)
(20,)
(2, 20)
```

My error is

```
TypeError: Length of y must be number of rows in z.
```

Why would that be? The dimensions look correct.

Comment: func, plt are not defined is code missing  this? import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: @DanPatterson I corrected the `plt` issue. The function is rather complicated---for discussion, it takes two inputs and returns an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs for `contour`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour): "**X and Y** must both be 2-D with the same shape as Z, or they **must both be 1-D such that len(X) is the number of columns in Z and len(Y) is the number of rows in Z.**"  (This is the version for 1D X and Y.)

Your basic problem here is that `Z` needs to be rectangular, so probably 20x20 in your case.  That is, think of a contour plot as putting levels on something like an image.

As best I can figure it out, here's a working version that's along the lines of what you want:

[image]

```
import pylab as pb    
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):
    return np.log(x**2 + y**2)

x = np.logspace( np.log10(5e4), np.log10(8e4), num=20) 
y = np.logspace(np.log10(5e4), np.log10(9e4), num=20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = f(X, Y)
print x
print y
print min(z.flat), max(z.flat), min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)

pb.show()
```

I think the key that you're not using [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) (although there are other means of getting this too).

Comment: How can I reshape the z-axis to create an array shaped (20,20)? At the moment, `func(x,y)` outputs 20 values, and x is 20 values.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: If you function only outputs 20 values, then it doesn't make sense to do a contour plot.  We don't know your function, we don't know what you want to plot to look like.  All you've said is "contour", so I'm telling you what you need to make a contour.

Comment: I have three dimensions of data: an x parameter, a y parameter, and a function with two arguments, x and y. What do you recommend as a plot?

Comment: I don't have enough information.  Since you write `f(x,y)`, when you say "20 values", do you mean 20 for each (x,y) pair?  A common thing is to have, say, 20 x values, and 20 y values, and then for each (x,y) pair you get 1 f(x,y), giving you 400=20x20 values.  That you could make a contour plot from.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I mean. 
Let's say the function is something simple, like `x**2 + y**2`. How would you create a contour plot of that such that the dimensions are correct?

Comment: x = np.logspace(1, 2, num=20)  yields x in the range 10 to 100, yours are very large and confusing...can you explain

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: What do you mean by first?  I create it before I use it.  That's all that's needed.  But the point is, I get a contour plot from the function call which is what you need.  Anyway, I'm tired of this.  This works, take it or leave it.

Comment: @Tom   Nice it works.  the need for logspace is a bit confusing since the range in values make it look linear.  If other people want, the can replace your x and np.logspace with    x = np.logspace(3, 4, num=20)  (repeat for y) to see amore pronounced affect with a more appropriate range for log data.  Nice job on catching np.meshgrid